# alert doesn't appear in localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code works fine in jsfiddle but when i run in the locahost, alert box doesn't appear while there is no error in the console too. What could be the reason. Can anyone help?

index.html

```
<title>App</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="movieList.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

movieList.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('something');
});
```

Comment: What does your javascript console say? Any errors?

Comment: When you say "localhost", do you mean you're running it from a local server and going to `http://localhost` or do you just mean you're opening the file locally?

Comment: no it doesn't show any errors

Comment: did you checked "prevent alerts from this page". try to close and open the tab again

Comment: yeah from local server like localhost/.....

Answer (score 2):

Script order matters. You need to load jQuery before you load your script because your script relies on jQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="movieList.js"></script>
```

If you were to open your javascript console in your browser (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>), you'd probably see an error saying something like `$ is not a function`.

If there are no errors, perhaps you've suppressed alerts for the page. Try replacing

```
alert('something');
```

With

```
console.log('something');
```

And keep an eye on your javascript console to see if the message gets printed. If it shows up, you've probably disabled alerts. To fix this, close and re-open the tab. It's recommended you use `console.log()` over `alert()` for debugging since alerts and other prompts can cause weird timing issues because of how they interrupt the javascript execution.

Comment: it doesn't work, and i didn't get any errors in the console

Comment: Then there's nothing we can do.

Comment: unfortunately console.log() also doesnot show anything, its strange

Comment: Then your script is never being run. Check in your browser developer tools Network tab to see if your `movieList.js` file is even being loaded. If you see a 404 error, it means it couldn't find the file.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery First

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="movieList.js"></script>
```

Comment: is movieList.js file in same folder that html?

Comment: yeah its in same folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    alert('something');
});
```

[.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tries, alert box appears as expected after i deleted all the browsing history. But i dont know what was the reason.